# Which is a sound scientific explanation that prevents rockets to fly in rarefied atmosphere?

Tags: atmosphere, rockets

The world has lost its atmosphere. It has flown away, because the magnetic field is weakened and solar flares are making everything slowly fly away in space.

NASA has its own rockets and shuttles and all these nice things but... they do not work anymore! They do not fly, they stay on the ground, or they fly a bit and then crash.

The question is: why? Which is a possible (sound) explanation for this?

Comment: Outer space has no air and that's the whole reason we use rockets there!

Comment: @Eleanore  If the Earth loses it magnetisphere the solar wind will slowly, repeat slowly, strip away the atmospehere over millions and billions of years.  So tt won't be happening during the time frame of future human history.  And if it doeshappen fast everyone will die for lack of oxygen except for the ones who build airtight moon bases and space habitats on the Earth or in outer space fast enough.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since before 1940, there has been no plausible explanation for a failure of rockets to work in a vacuum.  Simply put, rockets work *better* in vacuum than in thick air.

Now, your solar flares and magnetic storms that accompany them could still ground NASA and other spacecraft -- but not in a way related to the ongoing loss of the atmosphere.  Rather, the electromagnetic effects of the flares are *very* bad for microelectronics, and every spacecraft more sophisticated than a basic sounding rocket is critically dependent on computer electronics for functions like guidance.

Without guidance, it doesn't matter that the rocket engines still work (we'll handwave getting, say, an RS-25 Space Shuttle Main Engine to operate without its electronic controls) -- the rocket can't be kept on course well enough to reach even Low Earth Orbit, never mind navigate anywhere further from the Earth.  A pilot aboard wouldn't be able to communicate with ground control well enough even to manually (and inefficiently) fly a rocket into a particular orbit -- and once in *some kind of orbit*, unrelated to any intended mission, she'd be doing well to be able to do anything other than deorbit (that, at least, is thankfully simple: you can *see* your motion relative to the Earth when in low orbit, so you just need to thrust against it by an amount any astronaut going up in these conditions will have memorized).

End result: launching rockets wouldn't come to an end -- especially solid fuel rockets like most modern sounding rockets.  But launching *spacecraft* would be done, because the computers that make it possible would all be fried.

Comment: This is probably the best explanation, though if there's anyone who knows how to harden computers against EM radiation, it's NASA.

Comment: Oh, they do -- but what reason would they ever have had to harden the ones in Houston?

Comment: Well, even if Earth's magnetic field vanished tomorrow, it'd take an enormous amount of time for the atmosphere to blow away.  They would have both reason and opportunity to do so.

Comment: Sure, over that kind of time frame -- except where will they get hardened electronics?  All the fabs will be down, because *their* computers don't work; civilization itself would be teetering.

Comment: Let’s suppose that indeed this is the case, and we harden these things to keep up with the flares. 
Is it plausible to say that the more the situation degrades (less and less magnetic field force, less and less atmosphere, more and more flares), the more scientists would be required to update models of spacecrafts over time to adapt to the worsening situation?

Comment: It's really not difficult to harden ground stations against solar flares - you just need to put mass between yourself and the sun, and we have plenty of mass lying around. Water and dirt both make for great shielding, and if you need better shielding you just go deeper. It's only a challenge with spacecraft because mass is really expensive to get up there.

Comment: @Eleanore You have it -- it would be a continued course of repeatedly replacing or progressively shielding electronics as the solar situation gets worse.  Just to stay at current tech levels would be a continuous race against worsening conditions.

Comment: And this would be the case even in case of absence of flares but constant presence of solar winds, right?

Comment: Solar wind happens continuously now -- but we're protected, at ground level, by the Earth's magnetic field.  Lose that, and solar wind is one of the main causes of atmospheric loss (look at Mars -- lost its magnetic field, and over a billion years or so, lost most of its atmosphere).  But yes, if the magnetic field collapsed over, say, a century, it would be a race to protect electronics, power grid, etc. as it died down and relatively minor solar events became more relevant at ground level.

Comment: Wait a minute.  First, the early Soviet satellite launches surely used vacuum tube technology for guidance, didn't they?  Which IIUC would not have required much hardening.  And second, unmanned spacecraft are currently flying all over the solar system, outside of atmospheres, for months or years at a time, and some of them much closer to the Sun than the Earth is.  I guess their electronics are somewhat hardened, but if it works for them, why wouldn't it work for a near-earth rocket? which is sort of jdunlop's point.

Comment: @MikeMaxwell Sure.  Where can I buy a few thousand subminiature pentodes to build a computer equivalent to the chip in my (old tech) watch.

Comment: @Zeiss: Soviets didn't need a computer to launch the Sputniks into orbit, or for the Luna 3 to take pictures of the far side of the Moon; the guidance systems were more primitive, but worked well enough.  For that matter, the V-2 guidance systems were good enough to hit London.  And at any rate, a few thousand pentodes were not that expensive, although they would have required a fair amount of power.

Comment: Can you find any of that equipment in working condition today, though?  Or anyone alive who remembers how to build it?  There probably aren't ten thousand working submini pentodes (never mind all the same tube type -- of which there were dozens even in submini pentodes) left on Earth.  Remember, we're talking about a new situation, not the way things have always been.

Answer (score 11):

**They fly, but *landing*...**

As @Zeiss Ikon says, rockets fly better in vacuum than in atmosphere.  Getting a rocket to a set altitude or into an orbit is much easier than it was.

However, they cannot get back down to the surface of Earth without either:

1. an atmosphere to use for aerobraking and eventual slowing during landing (heat shields, wings and/or parachutes) - now that this is gone the only alternative is...
2. just as much delta v as they needed to get into orbit in the first place.  Given the limits imposed by the [Tsiolkovsky rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation), this makes Earth-to-orbit-to-Earth missions prohibitively expensive for most payloads.

To give an impression of just how bad this is - assume that a well-designed rocket that doesn't need to punch through the atmosphere can deliver 5% of its launch mass into low Earth orbit (LEO).  (For comparison, the Space Shuttle could deliver <1.5% of its launch mass into LEO.)  If it wants to land on an airless Earth safely, then only 5% *of the payload that reached LEO* can land - the rest is expended decelerating to a soft landing.  So a spacecraft with a launch mass of 4,000 tons will get 200 tons into orbit, of which only 10 tons will make it back to Earth.

This assumes that all goes well - if any of the rocket firings fail during the initial launch or during the de-orbit and landing then the payload (including humans) is hamburger because, again, with no atmosphere there's no fallback option to eject and parachute to safety.

Comment: so, hypothetically, what would happen if I tried to hydrobrake at 11 km/s by skimming the ocean?

Comment: ... and even a thin atmosphere is useful for slowing down significantly. They don't propulsion break on Mars, and Mars's atmosphere is pretty thin.

Comment: @JohnDvorak actually Mars missions do use retro rockets in addition to parachutes and airbags - the atmosphere just isn't dense enough to provide enough deceleration on its own.  See https://mars.nasa.gov/mer/mission/timeline/edl/ for an example.  As for hydrobraking at 11 km/s - water is effectively incompressible.  It is almost as bad as hitting concrete at human terminal velocity in atmosphere (not quite as bad, contrary to urban legend) but at 11 km/s there would be no practical difference.

Comment: @JohnDvorak:  See [Ethiopian Airlines Flight 961](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethiopian_Airlines_Flight_961) for what can happen if you don't get "hydrobraking" just right at 0.09 km/s.  I shudder to think what would happen at 11 km/s.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert any chance a plane could be designed for hydrobraking though? No jet nacelles below a certain line, a singular foil attached behind the COM such that any force to it will point the plane forwards instead of sideways? You'd still get immense forces if you scoop up too much water, so the foil would have to be designed to skim and not submerge. Would that be doable, or would just touching the water at 11km/s inevitably rip something out?

Comment: @JohnDvorak even with a billiard ball-smooth section of water and an indestructible unobtainium foil it's impossible due to the water surface following the curvature of the Earth - either the foil digs in and decelerates the spacecraft at an average (with higher peaks) of 600G over about 1km or the craft ricochets off the surface of the water in many pieces into an unstable orbit.  .50 cal rounds fired into water disintegrate (Mythbusters again) at < 1 km/s.  Kinetic energy is square of velocity, so 11 km/s is over 100 times more energy per unit mass - not survivable by any craft.

Answer (score 6):

### Kessler Syndrome

There's no physical principle that would prevent a rocket from functioning in a thin atmosphere, in fact, as others have mentioned, it would actually make things easier. What might prevent spaceflight, however, is what's known as "Kessler Syndrome." This can happen when the destruction of one or more spacecraft or satellites produces a hail of high speed shrapnel, which in turn destroys other spacecraft or satellites, producing still more shrapnel, eventually leading to the destruction of everything in orbit. With only the thin atmosphere at the edge of space to slow the fragments down, low earth orbit is ultimately filled with a cloud of shrapnel that could persist for centuries.

Realistically, this would only make staying in low earth orbit suicidal. As long as space launches passed through low earth orbit as quickly as possible the risk of collision could be minimized. However, if the scenario you are proposing is in the far-future, perhaps by that point in time there will be enough material in orbit that Kessler Syndrome would make transiting low earth orbit truly impossible. Alternatively, perhaps none of the space agencies of this setting have a powerful enough rocket on hand, or cannot afford (whether due to a shortage of material resources or funds) to build a powerful enough rocket to dash through low earth orbit with a useful payload.

Comment: Interesting idea.  It's worth adding that the minimum LEO altitude for Earth today is defined by the point at which the atmosphere has a noticeable effect.  If the atmosphere is entirely gone, then the minimum LEO is defined by the tallest mountain in the orbital path.  Which opens up a lot more close-in orbits that can be filled with rubbish.

Comment: Orbits that close will be unstable, as the Earth is not a perfectly uniform sphere.  mountains, ocean basins, and "mascons" will nudge the orbit chaotically.

Comment: @JDługosz and [oversized man-made structures](https://xkcd.com/1243/)

Answer (score 4):

There are no rockets that fly completely automatic, there needs to be at least someone to program a course and start it.

Since there was some cataclysmic event that robbed the earth of its atmosphere, all humans are dead, and no one can start the rockets.

Answer (score 1):

**Electrical failure**

The magnetic field has weakened, so solar flares will have a larger influence on the world. One way they can do this is EMP. All systems are simply fried. If the systems aren't fried or placed just before launch, they quickly fail when they meet the now seemingly more abundant solar flares as they go up.

Answer (score -2):

The design of the "bell" end of the rocket is based on the air pressure under which it is operating.  Thus, rockets that operate in vacuum are different than those used for launch.  You can learn about this from Scott Manley's videos on YouTube, for example.  This affects the efficiency and may or may not reduce the thrust below the point of usability.  And it's easy to change out the nozzle.

Rockets made for launch may also use aerodynamics for steering.  Moving a little fin is easy compared to vectoring the main thrust; likewise fixed little fins are used for *stability* and there is no mechanism to do the kind of careful balancing needed in any other way.  I think this is your best bet to be believable and understandable.

The priming and ignition systems may be tuned for or fundamentally rely on ambient pressure outside the rocket.

Rockets designed for launch stage may rely on air for cooling!

Comment: Rockets going to orbit spend only the first minute or so in thick enough air to be of use for stability, steering, or cooling.  This is why modern rockets typically have no or very small fins -- stability and guidance are both managed by thrust vectoring.  Also, a surface engine works fine in vacuum, it's just less efficient than a vacuum optimized engine (with its much larger nozzle bell).  Finally, igniters for solid motors don't depend on air, either oxygen or pressure, any more than a rifle cartridge does.